# Proof that the calculus of constructions extended with recursive types isn't strongly normalizing?

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus, normalization

What is the proof that the calculus of constructions, extended with recursive types (i.e., Fix at the type-level) isn't strongly normalizing?

Answer (score 10):

With general recursive types you can define the type

```
type T = T -> T
```

With that type you can type self-application -- and in fact, every term of the untyped lambda calculus, including any of the well-known fixed-point operators. For example, the Y operator:

```
Y = \f:T. (\x:T. f (x x)) (\x:T. f (x x))
```

Comment: It even suffices to have type $T = T \to A$ for some other type $A$.  Then $Y I_A = \Omega$ will have type $A$.
Of course, this is all because of the negative occurrence of $T$ in type $T \to A$.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a slightly more explicit version of what Andreas said.

The term $(\lambda x . x x) (\lambda x . x x)$ is not normalizing because it has exactly one $\beta$-redex, and when we reduce it we get back to the same term. But this term has the type $T$ for any type $T$ satisfying $T = T \to T$.